# How to make the user select a value and retrieve it?

Tags: vsto

I have a dynamic list of values that I want the user to select from, how is it possible to do it with VSTO ? Would it be possible to prompt a listbox (as a MessageBox ?) and retrieve the selected item ? Or could I add a listbox in the Ribbon ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add [DropDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbondropdown.aspx)/[ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribboncombobox) control to ribbon bar?

Alternatively, perhaps you could create a custom windows form and place the control on it. Then attach that form to an event, add-in start, button click, etc.